# docker compose and jenkins

Tags: jenkins, docker, continuous-integration, docker-compose

I have a Jenkins job I want to run `docker-compose up` for a deployment.
When I run it I get the error:

```
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson5937783564331081987.sh
+ export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:4243
+ DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:4243
+ /usr/bin/docker-compose up
Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http://localhost:4243 - is it running?
```

but when I login as the jenkins user into the ssh, i can run `docker-compose up` without a problem...Any solution? I tried `export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:4243` without luck.

Comment: so from jenkins you have tried with and without exporting DOCKER_HOST without it working? which protocols does the docker daemon listen to?

Comment: I have no root access to the machine, just ssh to user jenkins. So I cannot go really deep into it configs. I thought the problems could be solved through some jenkins configuration, since it is working over CLI

Comment: can you to not export DOCKER_HOST or set it to empty string in jenkins? so that docker clients fallback to default docker host (unix socket i guess) which hopefully is what happens via ssh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the Sysop do the changes here

http://blog.csdn.net/qiyueqinglian/article/details/46559825

then I put in my jenkins job

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:4243
```

Now it works.

Comment: hmm wasn't that what you had?

Comment: @mattias, there were additional changes with docker opts